# useTranslation hook ( i18next package) and material ui tab indicator bug

Tags: material-ui, i18next

I've noticed strange behaviour using material ui tabs with  i18next npm package (useTranslation hook) - for localize my buttons. The main problem is: bottom indicator doesn't recalculate its position after page reload, but when I comment my useTranslation hook - everything is ok. my hook looks like this at top of component:

```
const { t: tc }: UseTranslationResponse = useTranslation('common');
```

I don't see any dependency here or any asynchronicity problem why this happens. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. Just like you, I'm using react material tabs with i18next.
To solve this problem, I forced namespaces load on i18n initialization.
I don't know why this bug happens, but this workaround works for me.

```
i18n.init({ns: ['components', 'pages', 'common', 'generalData']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably loading your translations asynchronously? Using i18next-http-backend maybe?

Then you may not be using Suspense and also not waiting for the ready flag: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense